# open-ssl rand_bytes function causing memory leak

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, visual-studio-2022

I've created this class for my cryptography algorithms but i have this exception when rand_bytes function has been called. "0x00007FF92BA7C39B (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000."
I can't figure out where im causing memory leak.

```
namespace crypto
{
    struct PARAMS
    {
        const EVP_CIPHER* cipher;
        unsigned char* key, * iv; 
        int key_length, block_length;
    public:
        PARAMS() : cipher(NULL), key(NULL), iv(NULL)
            , key_length(0), block_length(0) {}
    };

    class CRYPT
    {
    private:
        struct PARAMS _params;

    private:
        bool GenerateKey() {
            this->_params.key = (unsigned char*)calloc(static_cast<size_t>(this->_params.key_length) + 1, sizeof(*this->_params.key));
            if (this->_params.key == NULL)
            {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, strerror(errno), "error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                return false;
            }

            if (this->_params.block_length != 0) {
                this->_params.iv = (unsigned char*)calloc(static_cast<size_t>(this->_params.block_length) + 1, sizeof(*this->_params.iv));
                if (this->_params.iv == NULL)
                {
                    MessageBoxA(NULL, strerror(errno), "error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // filling buffer with random bytes for key and iv
            if (RAND_bytes(this->_params.key, this->_params.key_length) != 1) return false;
            if (RAND_bytes(this->_params.iv, this->_params.block_length) != 1) return false;
            return true;
        }

    public:
        ~CRYPT() {
            if (this->_params.key) {
                memset(this->_params.key, 0, static_cast<size_t>(this->_params.key_length));
                free(this->_params.key);
            }
            if (this->_params.iv) {
                memset(this->_params.iv, 0, static_cast<size_t>(this->_params.block_length));
                free(this->_params.iv);
            }
        }

    public:
        bool init() {
            this->_params.cipher = EVP_aes_128_ctr();

            // now we can set key length and iv length
            this->_params.key_length = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(this->_params.cipher);
            this->_params.block_length = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(this->_params.cipher);

            // generate a key pair
            if (!this->GenerateKey()) return false;
            return true;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    crypto::CRYPT cr;
    if (!cr.init()) {
        puts("set-up failed!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: That's no memory leak. That's a battlestation! Errr... Null pointer access.

Comment: Are any or all of these `cipher(NULL), key(NULL), iv(NULL)` ever set to point at valid objects?

Comment: @user4581301 so it means this->_params.key is null after allocating memory?

Comment: Looks like you have `key` and `iv` covered and tested in `GenerateKey`, `init` sets `cipher`, but this doesn't seem to be tested.

Comment: @user4581301 true, I changed the code to find bug.

Comment: Run the program in the debugger that came with your other development tools. When the program crashes, the debugger will stop before exiting the program and let you look around to see exactly what was null and often dig back in the stack to see how it got there. If not, run the program again and step through , keeping an eye out for where the variable is set t null (or where it should have been set to something else.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't find anything that was set to null, _params.key and _params.key_length have both correct values before passing to rand_bytes function. I wrote a simple code to test rand_bytes it also causing crash. ```unsigned char x[32]; memset(x, 0, 32); if (RAND_bytes(x, 31) != 1) return false;```

Comment: Peculiar. Leads me to wonder if there's some initialization step that needs to be performed on Windows before you can call `RAND_bytes`, to set up the RNG for example, that has been missed. I don't think I can help with this one due to lack of experience, and particularly not at this hour. My brain probably turned to jelly an hour ago.